# Python Webscraping with BeautifulSoup not displaying full content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the text from a webpage which is embedded within the "td" tags that have a class="calendar__cell calendar__currency currency ".  As of now my code only returns the first occurence of this tag and class.  How can I keep it iterating through the source code. So that it returns all occurrences one by one.  The webpage is forexfactory.com

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.forexfactory.com/#detail=108867").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

body = soup.find("body")

article = body.find("table", class_="calendar__table")

actual = article.find("td", class_="calendar__cell calendar__actual actual")

forecast = article.find("td", class_="calendar__cell calendar__forecast forecast").text

currency = article.find("td", class_="calendar__cell calendar__currency currency")

Tcurrency = currency.text
Tactual = actual.text

print(Tcurrency)
```

Comment: use `find_all()` to get list with all elements which you can iterate with `for`-loop

Comment: @furas Yes thank you, I think its working but do you know why .prettify() isnt working on that piece of code.  When I try to use prettify I get "Result object has no object prettify"

Comment: how do you use it ? `BeautifulSoup.prettify(object)`?

Comment: do you use `prettify()` before you get text from object ? `string` doesn't have `prettify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `find_all()` to get all elements and then you can use `for`-loop to iterate it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.forexfactory.com/#detail=108867")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("table", class_="calendar__table")

for row in table.find_all('tr', class_='calendar__row--grey'):

    currency = row.find("td", class_="currency")
    #print(currency.prettify()) # before get text
    currency = currency.get_text(strip=True)

    actual = row.find("td", class_="actual")
    actual = actual.get_text(strip=True)

    forecast = row.find("td", class_="forecast")
    forecast = forecast.get_text(strip=True)

    print(currency, actual, forecast)
```

Result

```
CHF 96.4 94.6
EUR 0.8% 0.9%
GBP 43.7K 41.3K
EUR 1.35|1.3 
USD -63.2B -69.2B
USD 0.0% 0.2%
USD 48.9 48.2
USD 1.2% 1.5%
```

---

**BTW:** I found that this page uses JavaScript to redirect page and in browser I see table with different values. But if I turn off JavaScript in browser then it shows me data which I get with Python code. `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` can't run JavaScript. If you need data like in browser then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you didnt have to write out the fuction for me but is it greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain how Javascript is affecting this situation a little further I didnt completely understand.  Thanks

Comment: when I turn off JavaScript and uses your link then browser shows me data for `December 30` but when JavaScript works in browser then it redirects me to `December 23`. it redirects to https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=dec23.2019 . Problem makes `#detail=108867` in url.